# Preload polygons that are outside current map view in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When I zoom out or pan the map, the part of the polygon outside of the current view is first displayed empty, and then loaded. I need the polygon to be loaded in advance. How can I do this?

```
        <script>
            const bounds = [[-1900, 0], [2200, 8200]];
            const map = L.map("map", {
                crs: L.CRS.Simple,
                maxBounds: bounds,
                maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0,
                maxZoom: -0.6,
                minZoom: -3.2,
                minZoom: -2.8,
                zoomDelta: 0.5,
                zoomSnap: 0.5,
            })

            L.imageOverlay("map.jpg", bounds).addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        
            let latlngs = [
                [1714, 2549],
                [1776, 3336],
                [934, 3121],
                [836, 2382],
                
            ];

            L.polygon(latlngs, {color: "#fff", weight: 5}).addTo(map);
        </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT27e.jpg)

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#renderer-padding

Comment: So do I need to use canvas or svg for the solution? I found a plugin for solving a similar problem Leaflet.EdgeBuffer. I just don't know how to buffer polygons